# MySQL trigger - Update table2 on insert in table1

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert

What I want to do is to add some credit (10% of user´s credit) to user´s account with each 3rd, 6th, 9th and 12th (not more) user added into database under this user´s invite link (but invite link isn´t essential here - each user has index column with ID of his invitator).

So something like this (sorry for "pseudocode", I never had to use the trigger and probably won´t have to any soon, so I have no idea how to write it properly):

```
UPDATE accounts.credit = accounts.credit + (accounts.credit/10)
ON INSERT INTO users (AND when inserted row % 3 == 0 to some user)
WHERE k_user = this
```

Or is there any easier way how to do this? I could handle PHP, but I think the script can execute only if user visits the site...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using triggers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER INSERT ON users
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF NEW.id % 3 = 0 THEN
               UPDATE accounts SET credit = credit + (credit / 10) where k_user = NEW.id
           END IF;
       END;$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In the end I realised I don´t need necessarily do this in the database level and solved it via PHP. Just added some sql queries at the end of the function that handles the user registration. But your answer gave me some insight in the triggers...which could be handy.